# Are there ways to sidestep Python's indentation rules?

Tags: python, indentation

I'm assigning a bunch of values to dict keys, and some of the pairs semantically belong to others, but I can't indent to show possession because Python. This is akin to what I have:

```
boxColors["large trunk"] = "black"
boxColors["shoebox 1"] = "red"
boxColors["shoebox 2"] = "tan"
boxColors["jewelery box"] = "white"
boxColors["tacklebox"] = "green"
```

But, the shoeboxes are inside the trunk, and the jewelery box is inside shoebox 2. It would be much easier to see this relationship if I could indent things like this:

```
boxColors["large trunk"] = "black"
    boxColors["shoebox 1"] = "red"
    boxColors["shoebox 2"] = "tan"
        boxColors["jewelery box"] = "white"
    boxColors["tacklebox"] = "green"
```

Obviously I can't, because of how Python interprets whitespace-indentation. Is there some sort of no-op thing I could put at the start of a line to push the rest of the line over without changing its functionality? For example, if this were some sort of whitespace-significant version of C, I'd do this:

```
boxColors["large trunk"] = "black"
/**/boxColors["shoebox 1"] = "red"
/**/boxColors["shoebox 2"] = "tan"
/******/boxColors["jewelery box"] = "white"
/**/boxColors["tacklebox"] = "green"
```

But, alas, Python doesn't have C-style block comments. Is there a way to do what I want?

(Yes, I realize I'm deliberately subverting the language's design. Being able to subvert it in this manner would *improve* my code's readability. I know, I know, Python's rules are designed to enforce readability, but they're imperfect, and I think I've found an edge case.)

**Edit:** I've thought about separating sections with newlines, but that doesn't let me show multiple-level-deep ownership relationships, which I expect to have in droves.

Comment: Why are you using so many assignments in the first place, why not use a `{....}` literal instead?

Comment: You can put your data in a text file and read it from there, formatted however you want. Better yet, just express these relationships in your data instead of trying to do something silly.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense to me since you're always just using a single key to access `boxColors` and no nesting; are you sure that the data structure makes sense?

Comment: If those "boxes" are inside other "boxes", maybe you should use a nested dictionary, or a dedicated `BoxInABox` class. Or use different dicts/lists and merge them together after the assignments. Or just put some line comments above each group.

Comment: Also, there is no order in dictionaries, so as far as the data structure is concerned, there is *no relation* between those different keys anyway. If there is supposed to be a relationship, perhaps your data structure is wrong?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The relationship between items isn't something I care about _programmatically_; the items are, from the code's perspective 100% interchangeable, and that's intentional. The only reason I wanted to do this was to make it easier for humans to read. The things aren't technically boxes with colors, they're DOM elements and locators (mostly CSS selectors), and it's much cleaner to just reference loc["modal"] and loc["passwdField"] than to have to nest things à la loc["modal"]["passwdField"], because that gets messy if things are more than a couple levels deep.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use separate assignment statements. Use a dict literal. For example, if you're initializing an empty dict from scratch with these statements, you could instead do

```
boxColors = {
    'large trunk': 'black',
        'shoebox 1': 'red',
        ...
}
```

or if you're updating an existing dict,

```
boxColors.update({
    'large trunk': 'black',
        'shoebox 1': 'red',
        ...
})
```

Comment: Hmm, I guess I went too far in trying to change my code (it's related to what I'm doing at work, and I don't want to publicly post proprietary stuff). The problem with your approach is that what's going into this dict is a bunch of locators for a Selenium script to identify stuff by, and some of them use previously-added-to-the-dict ones (think concatenating of CSS selectors, e.g. one to find a <div>, and several that can be added to the end of it to find various elements within the <div>).

Comment: Also, is there a way to delete this question? I'm realizing that how far I went to change things for IP reasons essentially rendered it worse than useless. I tried the "delete" button, but it won't let me, because it's been answered. Is there a way that the community can vote on its deletion because of how badly I butchered it?